# Fresh installed Gatsby site does not build properly, running "index.html" in browser shows a broken site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Starting a new Gatsby site from the Starter Pack, while able to run it via `gatsby develop` or `gatsby serve` correctly, when I run it via `gatsby build`, the files in the /public folder are not able to run by themselves i.e. double-clicking on "index.html" to open it in browser. It only displays a stylized site (CSS works) but the functionality is broken along with a few other breaks like...

The image paths are broken, the click events are broken and even page linking is broken. What gives? Am I missing some dependency?

I've tried it in Mac and in PC. Using NPM and Gatsby CLI

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect your generated `.html`, you'll see that all the links there are root-relative (e.g `/page-2` vs. `./page-2`). If you try to load this file in a browser, it'll look for a `page-2` at your computer's root directory, which is not where the page is located.

You'll need a server that can serve the directory statically. That way each file in your directory will be mapped to an url & the browser can understand the absolute links in each page. That's why `gatsby serve` works, but clicking on the html itself doesn't.

Comment: Thank you! I was under the impression that a static file was exactly that... static as in, file browser static but am realizing quickly that the web means static differently.